# Como detectar si se realizo algun cambio en funcion update (antes de actualizar), laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy en el controlador de mi tabla de Productos, especificamente en el metodo Update, lo que quiero hacer es que si el campo "stock" no cambió, no lo actualize ( o simplemente tome otro parametro que yo le dare) y que si fue modificado se actualizen los campos stock y current_stock, mi pregunta es como preguntar si el campo "stock" de mi request cambió en comparación a lo que hay en la bd o modelo?, lo hice de la siguiente forma pero nose si es lo mas eficiente:

```
public function update(StoreProductPost $request, Product $product)
    {
        //Si el usuario dejo el stock igual, solo actualizo otros campos y entrego el valor del stock a campo stock
        if($product->current_stock == $request->stock){
            $request_data = $request->validated();
            $request_data["stock"] = $product->stock;
            $product->update($request_data);
            return back()
            ->withSuccess('Producto actualizado correctamente!');
        }else{ //sino actualizo el campo stock y current_stock
            $request_data = $request->validated();
            $request_data["current_stock"] = $request->stock;
            $product->update($request_data);
            return back()
            ->withSuccess('Producto actualizado correctamente!');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás repitiendo mucho código, al final estás haciendo el update siempre, se cumpla o no la condición. En mi opinión, sería mejor que hagas el update primero con los campos comunes y luego verifiques si hubo cambio para hacer el último update.

```
public function update(StoreProductPost $request, Product $product)
{
    $product->fill($request->validated())->save();

    if($product->isDirty('current_stock')){
        $product->update([
            "current_stock" => $request->stock
        ]);
    }

    return back()
        ->withSuccess('Producto actualizado correctamente!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la función **isDirty("column")** de tu modelo.

Cuando **isDirty("column")** haya cambiado, retornará **true**, también puedes escuchar cambios de tu modelo completo con **isDirty()**.

```
    if($product->isDirty('current_stock')){

        /*
        * Tu stock ha cambiado, acá puedes escribir tu logica.
        * Obteniendo valor antiguo: $product->getOriginal('current_stock')
        */
    }
```

Y adicionalmente con un Observer puedes manejar los eventos que desees que descuenten stock.
O manipular tu información antes de que guarde, ya que funciona similar a un trigger.

Comment: Por alguna razon no me funciona la funcin isDirty, me devuelve false cuando realizo un cambio, lo he probado con todos los campos del formulario

Comment: te recomiendo que vuelvas a mirar la docu de laravel sobre el isDirty(), porque al parecer, cuando cargas tu objeto directamente como parametro, ya viene actualizado. por ende dudo que funcione el isDirty

Comment: hice un dd() a la variable $product que es el objeto, pero viene antes de actualizarlo, los parametros "nuevos" estan en el request. En la documentacion (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#examining-attribute-changes), dice que se deben aplicar los cambios para poder usar la funcion isDirty(), significa que no puedo usarlo? es eficiente la forma la cual lo hice yo arriba en la pregunta?

Comment: la verdad siempre cuando modifico valores no cargo el la clase junto con el request. Podrías cargar el producto y asignar valores y para luego utilizar Dirty(). Creo yo que para este caso es mejor. Ya que sino deberías entrar a crear un observer BeforeUpdate de tu clase Product.